# How to change a view position and size at will

Tags: android, layout, view, size, position

I am working on an `Android Advertisement SDK`. This `SDK` will charge fetch `Advertisement` resource and play it in a WebView.

Depending on the content of the `Advertisement`, the `SDK` need to change the `WebView's` position and size. For Example, A banner advertisement will palce in the top or bottom of screen, some advertisement maybe place at center, left or right.

Now I need the users to place the `WebView` in `FrameLayout`, So I could change the position and size of `WebView` at will and don't affect other views. I could set `FrameLayout.LayoutParameters` to adjust position and size.

Obviously, this is a strong restriction for users. Maybe they want use `RelativeLayout` and others.

So is there anyone have ideas about my issue? I am trying to use fragment now and didn't know would it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out this question.

Every android app is base on a FrameLayout(android.R.id.content).When I need to change position of a view. I could remove the view from its current layout and add it to FrameLayout(android.R.id.content).

That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 approach to do this.
One is to set a layout ( forgot the name ) which allows you to set a component at custom position, size anywhere you want. As I remember it was 2 of those and one is deprecated form a version of Android. Google it those please, if you choose this method.

Other one it is with a trick:
Establish 9 positions (like the 9 pinch) and there use a predefined layout.
For eg. use a Relative layout.
1. if the banner need to be in position 1 than do x,y,z stuff  - rearrange a bit the others, do what you need if is on the top left.
2. if the banner it is a "merged position" 1 and 2 from grid (a a lot wider), than you do other corrections.
and do many cases what you need.

Good luck